# How come the URL of this page always remains the same when clicking on subpages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

No matter what hyperlinks I'd click on [this site](http://niniane.org/), the URL displayed in my browser bar always remains the same as the starting URL. Unless I right-click on the links and open a new tab. This is the first time I encounter this so I'm not sure what this kind of technology is called and how it was realized with html code.

Comment: @Variant is right. This method of building sites is not recommended: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/website-frames/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire page is constructed within a frameset. the hosting page remains the same and the navigation is done inside the frames.

if you view the page's source you'll see that it looks like this:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://ofb.net/~niniane" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

the whole browsing is done in the first frame which occupies 100% of the screen

Answer (score 1):

The whole page uses frameset instead of HTML. On click of any link, the page is opened in the same frame